# Problems getting Eclipse/Cocos2d-x to output relevant info to the console

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I have done quite a bit of looking around. I have tried using the CCLog and CCLOG with the #define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1 at the top.

My problem is that I can't really find where the debug statements are going. I would assume it's to the console but the build console is just full of build related statements. If I switch over to the Android console, it just contains generic info like:

```
[2014-01-11 13:08:29 - Superhero] Success!
[2014-01-11 13:08:29 - Superhero] Starting activity org.cocos2dx.simplegame.SimpleGame on device A0000037B2F93D
[2014-01-11 13:08:30 - Superhero] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.cocos2dx.simplegame/.SimpleGame }
```

I can't even get a printf to show up in any of the consoles. Does anyone know where the info should be going? I also tried LogCat but it's full of some pretty verbose debugging. I turned it to simple Debug mode but it doesn't show the logs I have inserted in the code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You may use adb command from command-line/Terminal.

```
adb logcat | grep cocos2d
```

This will print CCLog logs from your program.

Comment: 'grep' is for unix systems, you may search it's windows equivalent. I'm sorry that I'm not much familiar with windows commands.

Comment: This helped me. Someone suggested to use find, which I didn't have. I'm on OS X. Of course, grep is in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It does indeed put the log into the LogCat console. On the left hand side there is an option to create a filter.

Create one with the tag 'cocos2d-x debug info' and it should only give you relevant cocos2d-x info. Didn't see this question listed so I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in application.mk file of your project inside .jni

APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++1 -fsigned-char -DCCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1

and add a tag to logcat ex- cocos2dx-debug info